# mvc 5 dropdown list updates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dropdownlistfor

I am currently developing a site with asp.net MVC 5 and EF 6.
I would like a simple best practice approach on how to populate a drop down list with States bases on a selected Country in another drop down list.

I have a Country model and a StateModel with data from DB.
I have implemented a ViewModel with:

> ```
> [Display(Name = "Country")]
> public int SelectedCountryModelId { get; set; }
> public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList { get; set; }
> ```

And a similar one for StateModel.
I have a controller that loads the country list.

I am looking for a solution similar to this excellent one:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/730953/Cascading-Dropdown-List-With-MVC-LINQ-to-SQL-and-A

The above solution is in MVC 3 and I was hoping for some nicer solution with MVC. Is this possible without javascript code? I am not that skilled in javascript.

Comment: It would be better if you use javascript. If you work with MVC then try to work in javascript too. Otherwise it will be a little bit complex SGoldwin.

Comment: If you're going to develop for the web, get skilled in JavaScript. It's like saying I want to develop an Android app but I'm not that skilled in Java, or an iPhone app but that whole Objective-C thing is too much.

Comment: Not really true. In Java with JSF and PrimeFaces you can do Ajax really easy without have to code JavaScript. That function is build in JSF and PF. I was hoping for a something similar with MVC 5.

Comment: Is my request possible to solve with asp updatepanel and partial views?